# where is mercurial official repository

Tags: mercurial

The official mercurial web page can't find the entry of official repository, only download links, where is it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official Mercurial page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download#Source_packages) lists two repositories for getting the Mercurial source:

> - The [hg-stable](http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable) repository leads to stable releases.
> - The [hg](http://selenic.com/repo/hg) repository is the main development repository

Answer (score 0):

If you need a mercurial repository, try [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org).  If you're looking for the development snapshot of mercurlial try the [developer repos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/DeveloperRepos).